# Formatting an input String array

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to send an array of Strings to my server using Retrofit. If my method is:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@Post("postData")
Call<Response> postData(@Field("data") String[] data);
```

And my input is:

```
new String[]{"data1", "data2"}
```

Retrofit converts it to:

```
data=data1&data=data2
```

My question is: how do I get Retrofit to convert my array to this instead:

```
data=[data1,data2]
```

I am using Retrofit 2.0.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the docs, passing a List or array in the `@Field` annotation will result in a field pair for each item.  For everything else, Retrofit uses `String.valueOf`.  Source [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/http/Field.java#L29) and Jake Wharton's comments on changing it [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/519).

For now you're probably stuck making a custom class and overriding `toString`.  For example:

```
public class StringList {
    private List<String> mData;

    public StringList(List<String> data) { mData = data; }

    @Override
    public String toString() { return mData.toString(); }
}
```

And then your retrofit declaration becomes:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@Post("postData")
Call<Response> postData(@Field("data") StringList data);
```

Comment: Rats! Looks like you're right. [Here's](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1161) another link for those in denial (like me). Thanks for the help.